# How to show help files during installation of an application?

Tags: installshield

Our application has help files for various product features and also has a separate pdf for help with installation of the application itself. Is there a recommended way to show this to the user before he has actually installed the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically this is distributed with the software and reviewed during the "planning" phase.  It's a little late to be reading after you've clicked setup.exe.

Another thought would be to simplify your install.

Still, you could but a "Show Readme" button on the install that launches the PDF from the SUPPORTDIR or DISK1 folder.  But it can't be displayed from the INSTALLDIR folder because your  product hasn't installed yet.